# How to solve $(1+y^2)+(x-e^{-\arctan y})y' = 0 $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(1+y^2)+(x-e^{-\arctan y})y' = 0    $

I have to solve this differential equation. Normally  I would just put all the terms with y variable on one side and x on the other and integrate. However when I do that there is y' in both numerator and denominator. Or I will make it in a form of $y + Px =  Q$ and find integrating factor.  There is other method of using auxiliary equation but that does not work. None of these methods work.

Answer (score 3):

We need to solve $$(1+y^{2})dx+(x-e^{-\tan^{-1}(y)})dy=0$$

Let $P(x,y)=y^{2}+1$ and $Q(x,y)=-e^{-\tan^{-1}(y)}+x$ so, we can see that $P_{y}\not=Q_{x}$.

Now, we can find an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ such that $$\mu(y)P(x,y)+\mu(y)Q(x,y)y'=0$$ is exact equation.

This means, $$(\mu(y)P(x,y))_{y}=(\mu(y)Q(x,y))_{x}$$
So, we have $$(y^{2}+1)\mu'(y)+2y\mu(y)=\mu(y)$$
Solving, we have $$\mu(y)=\frac{e^{\tan^{-1}(y)}}{y^{2}+1}$$
Note that if $\tilde{P}(x,y)=e^{\tan^{-1}(y)}$ and $\tilde{Q}(x,y)=\frac{e^{\tan^{-1}(y)}x-1}{y^{2}+1}$ so $\tilde{P}_{y}=\tilde{Q}_{x}$
Solving by [exact method equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation#Solutions_to_exact_differential_equations)  (if you need more details here, you can say me and I will write the details of this section) we have the general solution:
$$\boxed{e^{\tan^{-1}(y)}x-\tan^{-1}(y)=c}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$(1+y^2)+(x-e^{-\arctan y})y' = 0$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$(1+y^2)x'+x=e^{-\arctan y} $$
Now it's a first order linear differential equation.